# How to use collection.distinct method on mongodb java driver 3.0

Tags: java, mongo-java-driver

I'm having trouble filtering the data from mongo, on plain mongo shell I can perform this query

```
db.context.distinct("flashVars")
```

but using the mongo-java-driver 3.0.0 the collection.distinct method requires a second parameter and returns a class DistinctIterable<>. However when I'm performing the operation the second line of the code throws Exception

```
MongoCollection<Document> contextCollection = mongoDBManager.getMongoCollectionByName("context");
DistinctIterable<HashMap> flashVarsDistinctIterable = contextCollection.distinct("flashVars", HashMap.class);
```

org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class

on the following line

```
DistinctIterable<HashMap> flashVarsDistinctIterable = contextCollection.distinct("flashVars", HashMap.class);
```

Any help will be appreciated.